# no MIDI sound from Terratec DMX 6fire

Tags: audio, midi

I have a Terratec DMX 6fire 24/96 sound card with NEC XR385 MIDI daughterboard installed in the front module. The OS I'm running is Windows XP. When I launch any MIDI application and select DMX 6fire Wavetable as an output device, I get no sound at all - only Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth works. What do I have to do to get MIDI sound from the NEC wavetable module? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The daughterboard has its own synthesizer. Show the list of all MIDI ports.

Comment: these are:Microsoft GS Wavetable SW Synth, MPU-401, DMX 6Fire MIDI, DMX 6fire Wavetable

Answer (score 0):

The 6fire has its own internal wavetable synthesizer, so the "DMX 6fire Wavetable" port certainly is wrong.

To send MIDI data to the daughterboard, you have to use the port that is routed to the daughterboard, either "MPU-401" or "6Fire MIDI".

Comment: well, whatever I choose except Microsoft GS Wavetable SW Synth, there is no sound. The same applies to MPU-401 and DMX 6fire MIDI.